# pygame, where does it save an image?

Tags: image, pygame

I am making a game and need to save a image of the screen, so i googled it and found this methode:

```
pygame.image.save(window, "screenshot.jpeg")
```

the problem is though, I don't know where it saves it, because it doesnt appear in the same folder as the programm is in for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an absolute filepath, like "C:\screenshot.jpeg"